# Python: Why am I receiving an AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python, attributeerror, contextmanager, temporary-directory

I am not reassigning the open keyword yet still receive this error. Any suggestions or direction to fix my error?

```
 with tempfile.mkdtemp() as test_dir:
        print(test_dir)
```

`AttributeError: __enter__`

I am also new to python and I am having a hard time understanding these concepts.

Comment: *"mkdtemp() returns the absolute pathname of the new directory"* Need I say more?

Comment: Check out this for an info on context managers. What are going expecting to happen with your code? https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html

Comment: @liamhawkins I wanted to create a temporary directory and I know that tempfile.TemporaryDirectory creates a 'temporary directory', but doesn't show up as an actual directory or folder to input files in before the garbage collector gets too it. I wanted to create an actual directory, assign it a variable name and input files or do whatever operation I want on the directory.

Comment: Not all objects can be used in a `with` statement. Have you tried `test_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()` instead?

Comment: Then you don't need a `with` statement. There's no context to manage. The only reason I can think of for *wanting* a context manager here would be if you wanted the directory to be deleted on exit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using mkdtemp incorrectly. [mkdtemp](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) returns the path name as str, not a context manager.

If you want a context manager for managing a temporary directory, you need to use [TemporaryDirectory](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory), which is available from Python 3.2 and above.

Comment: Using tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() creates a file like 'tmpa665vhxn' that has the type 'file' it is not an actual directory. I would like to make an actual directory I can utilize that is temporary.

Comment: What tells you that `tmpa665vhxn` is a regular file? It creates a directory for me.

Comment: @chepner I printed the 'directory' name went to the Temp directory in AppData and looked for the exact name and scrolled over to view the type.

Answer (score 0):

Though I see some of you have answered the problem I would like to add my answer for better clarity.

*correct* approach:

```
       with open(fullname, "r") as file:
            content = file.read()
```

*incorrect* approach:

```
       with open(fullname, "r").read() as file:
```

Reason: when you add `.read()` then its string and not file handler and string is not having built in `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods and where as file handler has two built-in methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`